# C# Datatable query

Tags: c#, linq

I want to search two string in datarows.For example;

```
string1="ex"
string2="ex2"
row1={'ex','ex2','ex3'....}---->True
row2={'ex3','ex1','ex2'....}---->True
row3={'ex2','ex5','ex6'....}---->False
```

Each line must have a value of two strings..
For This,

```
for (counter = 0; counter < array.Count; counter++)
        {
            int index=0;
            ArrayList array3 = new ArrayList();
            array3 = Split(array[counter].ToString());
            foreach (DataRow row2 in data.Rows)
                foreach (object obje in row2.ItemArray)
                {
                    //Proceeds
                    }
                }
        }
```

I coding something.But I do not want to deal with pollution in the code...
Is there an easy way to select method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = data.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(r => r.ItemArray.Contains(string1) || r.ItemArray.Contains(string2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do something like this:

first define a `DataView`

`DataView dv = new DataView(dt)` where `dt` is a `DataTable`.

After apply `RowFilter`

`dv.RowFilter = "CONTAINS(ColName, 'ex1') AND CONTAINS(ColName, 'ex2')"`.

Hope this helps.